# Border pixels are overlapping

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure this out.

I want the colored border to overlap the grey border. However, the border refuses to overlap the bottom border.

Here's a picture: 
http://gyazo.com/bc4cbaab9bfa3a173709309ad64f880e.png

The code for the borders is:

```
<li>
            <div class="content blue-border">
                <span class="icon-uniE601"></span>
            </div>
        </li>


.sidebar ul li {
    background-color: #f2f2ea;
    border-right: 1px solid #dfdfd7;
    border-top: 1px solid #dfdfd7;
}
.content
{
        border-left: solid 5px #0094ff;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
}
.content span
{
    height: 70px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 70px;
font-size: 2em;
color: #787878;
}
.sidebar ul li:hover
{
    background-color: black;
}
.sidebar ul li:first-child
{
    border-top: none;
}
ul li 
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.blue-border
{
    border-left: solid 5px #0094ff;
}
.orange-border
{
    border-left: solid 5px #ff6a00;
}
```

And here's the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/bG8Wb/2/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
element_that_needs_to_shift {
position:relative;
top:1px;
}
```

...

Is this what you wanted?

```
.sidebar ul li {
background-color: #f2f2ea;
border-right: 1px solid #dfdfd7;
/*border-top: 1px solid #dfdfd7;*/
}
```

Comment: Partly, but I want the actual border to appear there to make it look cleaner. I'm looking into the top: 1px right now

Comment: If I were you, to make it cleaner and simpler, I would make those 5px color borders separate elements with `display:inline-block` and set their width, height, and background color.